# How to copy keyframes from graph editor to another object

Tags: graph-editor

Is it possible to copy the keyframes from one object to another, in the graph editor? The only way I found was the link animation data. But I would like to know if its possible using the objects keyframes to be transferred like copy-paste, but nothing is happening. I'm trying to copy the keyframes, then select the other object and paste, but its greyed out.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is greyed out? Copy-paste should work but maybe share your file so that we try?

Comment: Here's the file @moonboots. the timeline has 2 frames of the cube object. I try to copy those frames, then select the cylinder, and paste into the cylinders timeline, and get the message alert: No selected F curves to paste into.

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=45aPMBAQ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/45aPMBAQ/)

Comment: Gordon's answer is correct  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy keyframes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the *Graph Editor*, but to paste them on a different object with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, there has to be a channel to paste them to. And an object only gets a channel if it has a keyframe somewhere.

So for example, if you want to copy your rotation keyframes from one object to the other, just select the second object, go to frame #1 and hit <kbd>I</kbd> > *Insert Keyframe* > *Rotation*. Now you can select the first one, copy the keyframes, select the second object and paste the keyframes there.

The thing is, other than linking animation data from one object to another which will result in the same animations on the second object, with copy+paste you can do something else: for example, copy *Rotation* keyframes and paste them into *Location* channels (in this case, the values will be converted from degree into radians) or *Scale* channels.

And instead of placing them on the original frames, if you copy keyframes that animate an object say in a range of frames 1 to 20, if you go to frame 11 and paste them there, they will now animate the object from 11 to 30.

If the channel you are pasting the keyframes to already has a keyframe where a new one gets pasted, the original one will be replaced.

Or if you copy rotation keyframes, and the object you want to paste to has location and rotation keyframes and you select them all, the keyframes will only be pasted into the rotation channels, i.e. whenever one or more rotation channels are selected, nothing will be pasted into the location channels.

But if you select only location channels, the rotation keyframes will be pasted there, usually X to X values, Y to Y and Z to Z.

This is just a quick overview, I guess there is more to know about copying keyframes.